# Turtlebot doesn't start rotating on calibration

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's almost the same with [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/2063/turtlebot-calibration-still-waiting-for-scan) but I open as new question since that question is not closed and `Turtlebot` software must have been updated since then.

Calibration movement doesn't start and keeps saying "Still waiting for imu". Stdout result is below (long, sorry). On other turtlebots calibration go properly. I found that the green power light on `iRobot Create` goes off with the beep sound when I start running calibration `launch` file, even though `dashboard` still shows the battery amount and breakers in green.

Env) Ubuntu 10.04, `ROS electric` as well as `turtlebot-robot`

```
turtlebot@turtlebot-3:~$ roslaunch turtlebot_calibration calibrate.launch 
... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/eff803fe-1004-11e1-bc0b-485d6032f3ac/roslaunch-turtlebot-3-9308.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://turtlebot-ip:59709/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /openni_camera/depth_time_offset
 * /openni_camera/image_mode
 * /kinect_laser/output_frame_id
 * /openni_camera/depth_rgb_translation
 * /pointcloud_throttle/max_rate
 * /openni_camera/depth_mode
 * /openni_camera/shift_offset
 * /scan_to_angle/min_angle
 * /kinect_laser/min_height
 * /openni_camera/depth_rgb_rotation
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/max_height
 * /scan_to_angle/max_angle
 * /kinect_laser/max_height
 * /rosdistro
 * /openni_camera/projector_depth_baseline
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/output_frame_id
 * /rosversion
 * /openni_camera/debayering
 * /openni_camera/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_camera/image_time_offset
 * /openni_camera/depth_registration
 * /kinect_laser_narrow/min_height
 * /openni_camera/rgb_frame_id

NODES
  /
    kinect_breaker_enabler (turtlebot_node/kinect_breaker_enabler.py)
    openni_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    openni_camera (nodelet/nodelet)
    pointcloud_throttle (nodelet/nodelet)
    kinect_laser (nodelet/nodelet)
    kinect_laser_narrow (nodelet/nodelet)
    scan_to_angle (turtlebot_calibration/scan_to_angle.py)
    turtlebot_calibration (turtlebot_calibration/calibrate.py)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://turtlebot-ip:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[kinect_breaker_enabler-1]: started with pid [9329]
process[openni_manager-2]: started with pid [9330]
process[openni_camera-3]: started with pid [9331]
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [9332]
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [9333]
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [9345]
process[scan_to_angle-7]: started with pid [9350]
process[turtlebot_calibration-8]: started with pid [9362]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415783.246879] has_gyro True
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415783.368377] Estimating imu drift
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415783.670546] Still waiting for imu
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415783.972455] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415784.274242] Still waiting for scan
[kinect_breaker_enabler-1] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/eff803fe-1004-11e1-bc0b-485d6032f3ac/kinect_breaker_enabler-1*.log
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415784.575880] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415784.877857] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415785.179778] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415785.481708] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415785.783952] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415786.086041] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415786.387849] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415786.690298] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415786.992970] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415787.295427] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415787.597576] Still waiting for scan
[ INFO] [1321415787.648486655]: [/openni_camera] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1321415787.649516784]: [/openni_camera] 1. device on bus 001:07 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00364856520048A'
[ WARN] [1321415787.653199988]: [/openni_camera] device_id is not set! Using first device.
[ INFO] [1321415787.733836961]: [/openni_camera] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:7 with serial number 'A00364856520048A'
[ INFO] [1321415787.780257377]: rgb_frame_id = 'kinect_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1321415787.787665082]: depth_frame_id = 'kinect_depth_optical_frame' 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415787.899734] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415788.202021] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415788.504294] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415788.813604] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415789.115867] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415789.418101] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415789.720129] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415790.022076] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415800.632698] Still waiting for imu
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415800.934589] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415801.238831]  ... imu drift is -0.358059 degrees per second
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415801.543371] Still waiting for imu
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415801.845179] Aligning base with wall
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321415802.149779] Still waiting for imu
^C[turtlebot_calibration-8] killing on exit
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11956/turtlebot-doesn%27t-start-rotating-on-calibration/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-11-15**:
does it actually halt? ..it seems like it gets the imu data if it calculates the drift.  sometimes when the create is running the light goes off but it's still running? when it says aligning base with wall it is trying to command the base to move.. check to see if cmd_vel is being published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Today calibration is successful. What I did before trying calibration is to re-do [Turtlebot bringup tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/TurtleBot%20Bringup#On_Your_TurtleBot) (I remember I did it even before I asked this question). Anyway thank @mwise_wg and all!

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0